According to Huygens' Princple, what happens to secondary wavelets when the sphere encircling the secondary source intersects a mirror?
A parallel light beam travelling towards a convex mirror. Wavefronts are shown with dotted lines.
Consider the wavefront at the instant when the rays are just about to touch the mirror. Say, we have to find the wavefront at a time $t$ after this instant. If we create Huygens' construction using points on this wavefront as secondary sources, from each source spherical wavelets would emerge. But if I simply draw spheres of radius $ct$, they may intersect the mirrors depending on the value of $t$.
The wavefront at time $t$ should be the surface of tangency of these spheres, but how do we determine it here?


The spherical wavelets get reflected by the mirror.
This will look this:

Then the tangent surface of all these reflected wavelets
will give the new wavefront at time $t$.
